# Pure as3 hgroup/vgroup components

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Was wondering, maybe someone knows components similar to Flex SDK HGroup/Vgroup that can be used in pure as3, w/o Flex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of as3 libs that have components like this.

[Minimalcomps](http://www.minimalcomps.com) has an HBox and a VBox that may give you what you're looking for.

There is also [Feathers](http://feathersui.com/) if you're looking for something using Stage3D